# Why has vim started launching the ilist on FocusGained?

Tags: terminal, mouse

Recently, on Debian Sid (accessed via SSH from an ArchLinux machine using [Terminator](https://gnome-terminator.org/)), something has started triggering the `[I` / `:ilist` function whenever vim gains focus. If I start vim without arguments I get `E349: No identifier under cursor`.

Nothing in the `au BufEnter` list looks relevant, and `au FocusGained` is empty. I have no vimrc in my home folder, and the only line in vimrc.local was `set ttymouse=`. In the comments, it was discovered that `set ttymouse=` is necessary to reproduce the problem.

`vim --version` is 8.2 installed from the [official sid package](https://packages.debian.org/sid/vim). My `$TERM` is `xterm-256color`. The ability to detect terminal focus was [introduced in patch 2345](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/681fc3fa782e99fe69ed2c83c3e29109d2d61e1a#diff-de432db93b351dd11d91c892d506b5ba9de1c98ef632d358c8590a312ed5a18aR2066), so only systems with fairly recent vim packages are able to reproduce.

For now, I'm avoiding the problem by adding `set t_fd=` and `set t_fe=` in the system's vimrc.local (as suggested by [`:help focus`](https://vimhelp.org/term.txt.html#xterm-focus-event)), but I'd like to figure out what's actually causing it. What's doing this and how can I turn it off?

It does not reproduce inside `vim --clean` unless I manually run `:set ttymouse=`

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! How did you get to `t_fd=` and `t_fe=`? It's odd that I don't see those in my Vim... I'm also on Linux and using `xterm-256color`... You mentioned accessing it via SSH, but what is the terminal emulator you're using on the local machine? Sometimes it might be related to some incompatibility between Vim (or the terminal settings for `xterm`) and the terminal emulator you're using not having support to some specific features Vim is trying to use... Also, what's the version of Vim on your Debian machine? How about Arch/Ubuntu, same version?

Comment: You can also try `vim --clean` to see if the problem still happens when you don't have any vimrc or plug-ins loaded... (Including the system-wide vimrc shipped by Debian.) It would be nice to check whether that makes a difference or not...

Comment: @filbranden Edited question to clarify. Also `vim --clean` is a fantastic thing I didn't know existed.

Comment: Looks like this feature was only introduced in Vim 8.2.2345 (https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/681fc3fa782e99fe69ed2c83c3e29109d2d61e1a) from January 14th, 2021 (two weeks ago.) The Debian sid package has version 8.2.2367, so it seems it includes this patch. I expect this explains why you're seeing this on Debian and not the others (which probably have slightly older packages...)

Comment: @filbranden that would explain why focus is suddenly being detected, but not why the behavior doesn't occur on Arch, which has patch [2380](https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/vim-runtime/), nor why FocusGained should result in `[I`

Comment: See [line 2066 in `src/term.c`](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/681fc3fa782e99fe69ed2c83c3e29109d2d61e1a#diff-de432db93b351dd11d91c892d506b5ba9de1c98ef632d358c8590a312ed5a18aR2066) in that patch, that should explain the `[I`. I'm betting what's happening is that your Terminator doesn't recognize those special sequences... Can you try it under actual `xterm` or something like `urxvt` or `gnome-terminal`?

Comment: @filbranden It reproduces under `xterm` but not `urxvt`... i note that the line you linked in the source code is gated by `if (use_xterm_like_mouse(term))` and if i remove `set ttymouse=` from vimrc.local the problem goes away

Comment: I can reproduce this with Vim 8.2.2425 in XTerm 363 and Terminator 2.0.1 after setting `TERM=xterm-256color` (this is a critical step; I can't repro it with my default of `TERM=st-256color`) on my Void system. I have no idea what the solution for this is, but this sounds like something that should be reported to the Vim bug tracker.

Comment: I *think* the problem is that XTerm sends different escape codes than Vim is expecting: looking at the showcmd it sends `<Esc>[I`, but `t_fe` is `<Esc>[?1004h`. This is also a problem with the focus out (sends `<Esc>[O`, but `t_fd` is `<1b>[?1004l`), but it's just that `[O` isn't a command whereas `[I` is. One solution would be to set those `t_` values to the one the terminal sends (or something? that doesn't work for me either; this entire terminal stuff always confuses me).

Comment: *I think the problem is that XTerm sends different escape codes than Vim is expecting*  No, those are 2 different sets of sequences.  The first set toggles the feature on and off.  The second set tells Vim which sequences the terminal will send when the window gains the focus or loses it, so that Vim knows `FocusGained` or `FocusLost` should be fired.  Relevant issue: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/7755

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119088/discussion-on-question-by-dan-why-has-vim-started-launching-the-ilist-on-focusga).

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a [genuine bug in vim](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/7755), which was fixed by the patch [8.2.2428](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.2.2428). Both the [Arch](https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/vim/) and [Debian](https://packages.debian.org/sid/vim) packages have now been updated to include this patch, so `pacman -Syu` or `apt-get upgrade` (respectively) will fix the problem.

The escape sequence terminal emulators send when they gain focus [is `\<Esc>[I`](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/681fc3fa782e99fe69ed2c83c3e29109d2d61e1a#diff-de432db93b351dd11d91c892d506b5ba9de1c98ef632d358c8590a312ed5a18aR2066). When the ttymouse vim option has been cleared, even though vim sends the terminal `\<Esc>[?1004h` to indicate it supports focus events, it fails to recognize the `\<Esc>[I` it receives in response.

Instead, it behaves as it would if I had literally pressed Escape, followed by `[I`, and tries to launch the [identifier list](https://vimhelp.org/tagsrch.txt.html#%5BI).

Workarounds include setting a `$TERM` that doesn't support focus events (e.g. `TERM=st-256color`), enabling `ttymouse`, or disabling focus events in vimrc with `set t_fd= t_fe=`.

Credit to [@filbranden](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/18609/filbranden), [@martin-tournoij](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/51/martin-tournoij), and [@user938271](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/17449/user938271) for finding this answer in the question comments.

Comment: Thanks for posting a summary as answer here! :-)