# Stop vim triggering activity when swapping tmux windows

Tags: tmux

In my `tmux` config I have `focus-events` and `monitor-activity` enabled to detect any changes that occur in other windows. When I open a `vim` session in one window and switch to another window, a focus event is immediately triggered on the old window containing the `vim` session.

Why is this occurring? I was under the impression that activity actions only get triggered when something happens in the other windows in the background. Is `vim` sending some sort of inactive session activity trigger which is causing the immediate activity action? How can I stop this from being triggered while still preserving the other activity actions that are being monitored by `tmux` in the background?

Comment: Not sure how tmux detects activity. Perhaps it is enough to disable Focus events in Vim: `:set eventignore=FocusLost,FocusGained`

Comment: Possibly related? https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/28953/51

Comment: And also see: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/18515/51

Comment: Disabling focus events helps prevent this problem. Setting just either `FocusLost` or `FocusGained` works too.